# Read a text file. Search for a text based on pattern and print all the matches in another text file

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I would like your assistance in writing a python code to read a text file. Search for text based on a pattern and print the matching text to another text file.

= Sample File contents =
1111/app/abc.jsf111. asdvvas/applet. This text is /apple.jsf which has apples. Also, this text could have /app.jsf

== Pattern ==

/app*.jsf

== Matches ==

/app/abc.jsf

/apple.jsf

/app.jsf

Here's my code:

```
import re

source = open("test.txt", "r")
dest = open("op.txt", "w")

pattern = re.compile('/app*jsf')

for line in source.readlines():
    matches = pattern.findall(line)

    for word in matches:
       dest.write(line+"\n")

dest.close()
```

My Output file (op.txt) is blank.

Comment: Regex should be `/app.*jsf`

Comment: `p*` is "0 or more p characters". You want `/app.*jsf`. `.*` = zero-or-more of ANY character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern = re.compile('/app[^\.]*jsf')
#or maybe just
pattern = re.compile('/app.*jsf') #if your filename can have multiple periods in it eg app.app.app.jsf
```

should work ...

```
regex("app*")# will match ap, app, appppp, appppppppppp
```

however it will not match anything other than p's after the initial ap, because in a regex a star (`*`) means **0 or more**  it is not the same as the wildcard in operating systems directory searches

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
pattern = re.compile('/app*jsf')
```

with:

```
pattern = re.compile('/app.*jsf') # .* means any character any number of times
```

`re.compile('/app*jsf')` only matches **/apjsf**, **/appjsf**, **/apppjsf**, **/appppjsf** and so on which is not desired and probably not present in your text file. That is the reason for empty file.

Comment: Perhaps change `*` to `*?` to make it non-greedy.